# ASP.net multiselect dropdownlist load on demand

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, combobox

Can you please someone let me know come cross to multiselect dropdownlist load on demand like the below

http://www.obout.com/combobox/aspnet_integration_checkboxes_ondemand.aspx
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/populatingwithdata/autocompletesql/defaultcs.aspx

I am looking for dropdown control multiselect load on demand for about 1 year now cant find any control like that for free.

I am using ASP.NET 3.5 i dont mind if anyone come such control even with jquery.

Thanks very much.

Comment: I don't know of any brown-and-serve "control" that does this, but you mention that you're not against using jQuery so I guess you could code a custom one.  You'd just bind data manually via AJAX calls in response to UI events.  The .NET side of things wouldn't be providing anything other than the server resources that the AJAX requests would call.  And writing it manually sure beats waiting for a whole year for someone else to do it :)

Comment: I have pages could have no limit the number of those controls on the page. I am just wondering if anyone wrote such control with easy to manage.

Answer (score 1):

This one is easy to implement, although it isn't as pretty as the ones in your link:
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1591-multiselect-dropdownlist-in-aspnet-using-csharp-40-.aspx

It's written in C# and i'm running it in Visual Studio 2010 with Ajax Controls.
Hope this helps!

Comment: This one is not load on demand. is pretty easy to create such controls. I have tried few telerik controls they still dont work in every case. Thanks